# SonarQube 5.2 / LDAP 1.5.1 plugin : admin cannot change password

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

After installing the LDAP plugin you cannot change the admin password, even if you put sonar.security.localUsers=admin in the configuration file and restart. You can goto security\users and use the lock icon but then you get an 'The 'previousPassword' parameter is missing' error message.

Is this a bug?

Local users should be able to change their password. Workaround: remove LDAP configuration, change password, restore configuration is awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug that will be fixed in 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different known bugs:

- for admin, it is impossible to change its own password in the "Users" page. The workaround is to go to the profile page and update the password. Related [jira ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7011), not fixed yet but there is a workaround.
- when using the LDAP plugin, it is not possible to update a technical account password. Related [jira ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7036), fixed in 5.3.